# Unexpected Behavior from Python Multiprocessing Pool Class

Tags: python, linux, multiprocessing, pool

I am trying to utilize Python's multiprocessing library to quickly run a function using the 8 processing cores I have on a Linux VM I created. As a test, I am getting the time in seconds it takes for a worker pool with 4 processes to run a function, and the time it takes running the same function without using a worker pool. The time in seconds is coming out as about the same, in some case it is taking the worker pool much longer to process than without.

**Script**

```
import requests
import datetime
import multiprocessing as mp

shared_results = []

def stress_test_url(url):
    print('Starting Stress Test')
    count = 0

    while count <= 200:
        response = requests.get(url)
        shared_results.append(response.status_code)
        count += 1

pool = mp.Pool(processes=4)

now = datetime.datetime.now()
results = pool.apply(stress_test_url, args=(url,))
diff = (datetime.datetime.now() - now).total_seconds()

now = datetime.datetime.now()
results = stress_test_url(url)
diff2 = (datetime.datetime.now() - now).total_seconds()

print(diff)
print(diff2)
```

**Terminal Output**

```
Starting Stress Test
Starting Stress Test
44.316212
41.874116
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `apply` function of `multiprocessing.Pool` simply runs a function in a separate process and waits for its results. It takes a little bit more than running sequentially as it needs to pack the job to be processed and ship it to the child process via a `pipe`.

`multiprocessing` doesn't make sequential operations faster, it simply allows them to be run in parallel if you hardware has more than one core.

Just try this:

```
urls = ["http://google.com", 
        "http://example.com", 
        "http://stackoverflow.com", 
        "http://python.org"]

results = pool.map(stress_test_url, urls)
```

You will see that the 4 URLs get visited seemingly at the same time. This means your logic reduces the amount of time necessary to visit N websites to N / `processes`.

Lastly, benchmarking a function which performs an HTTP request is a very poor way to measure performance as networks are unreliable. You will hardly get two executions which take the same amount of time no matter whether you use `multiprocessing` or not.